# How to have the AFTER separator in Xtend just behind last item

Tags: xtext, xtend

I use Xtend to generate some textual output from my Xtext grammar. My question is really simple, but I cannot figure it out reading the documentation and examples, so please give me advice!

Let us assume, I have a list with some items. I generate for every item a line within a FOR loop using the SEPARATOR feature. At the end I want to have a final separator using AFTER. Here is an example code to demonstrate it:

```
val list = #["a", "b", "c"]
'''
«FOR item : list SEPARATOR "," AFTER ","»
   «item»
«ENDFOR»
'''
```

In this way, I receive the following output:

```
a,
b,
c
,
```

Now the question: How can I have the final `,` separator immediately behind `c` and not on the new line? It's very important to me for proper formatting of my output (it's more complex than `a,b,c` in reality and the position of the separator matters). I want to have this:

```
a,
b,
c,
```

Experts, please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your simple example, as SEPARATOR and AFTER are the same, you should skip the separator/after stuff entirely and just use

```
'''
   «FOR item : list»
      «item»,
   «ENDFOR»
'''
```

The newlines after FOR and ENDFOR are skipped by Xtend's whitespace detection. The problem is that AFTER is applied after the loop is executed, and your loop-body contains a trailing newline that goes into the output (grayspace). You can overcome this by writing the entire loop in one line, e.g.

```
'''
   «FOR item: list SEPARATOR ',\n' AFTER ',\n'»«item»«ENDFOR»
'''
```

and extract a method for when the loop's body becomes to long. For better readability, you can add any number of whitespaces within the guillemets, e.g.

```
'''
   «FOR item: list SEPARATOR ',\n' AFTER ',\n'»«
      item
   »«ENDFOR»
'''
```

For smaller bodies, you might also consider prefer join()

```
'''
   «list.join(',\n')»,
'''
```

or more general map(), reduce() whatsoever.

Comment: Hello Mr. Koehnlein, thanks for your ideas! Even the first proposal would solve my case (as simple as it is, it somehow escaped me), but I appreciate to learn multiple approaches to handle similar issues.